# Agile Accelerator-You can not change the end date after the sprint has started

Tags: managed-package

I am tring to update "end date" for current sprint in Agile Accelerator tool, but its giving me following error message.

```
FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION

[object Object]: You can not change the end date after the sprint has started.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't the error message clear? If you started the sprint (per your word, "current", you have) then you may not change the end date.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But due to some reason, we need to change end date of current sprint, so how can we do it?

Comment: I tried to update from backend , using query to 'agf__ADM_Sprint__c' table, still its not working.

Comment: I suggest you contact the makers of the managed package. If you can't remove the validation rule yourself, then you won't be able to update that value at all. I suggest you attempt to stop the current sprint first, either by changing data or by using the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Editing end/startdate of a current sprint is possible with a little patience

1. Clone Sprint, save under different name
2. Edit Start / End Dates as you need
3. Move all work items to cloned sprint
4. delete old sprint
5. rename cloned sprint to old sprint name